# jQuery Nestable отловить событие

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как отловить событие изменения позиции элемента(перетаскивания) в [jQuery Nestable](http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/)

Код вида

```
$(document).on('change', '.dd-handle', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert();
});
```

не работает :(

Comment: Ловить нужно изменения в `.dd`,  а не `.dd-handle`

Comment: Допустим, а каким образом тогда получить к примеру id текущего элемента(`<div class="dd-handle" data-id="1">Item 3</div>`), т.е. который был перемещен ?

Comment: А что вам даст эта информация одного перемещенного элемента? Нужно получать весь список ` $('.dd').nestable('serialize');`

Comment: У меня там вывод категорий, если получать весь список, необходимо будет обновлять все категории в БД каждый раз, что не есть хорошо.